# Necessary and sufficient condition for random sum of independent RVs to be a martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, martingales, poisson-process

Let $M$ be a Poisson random measure on $(0,\infty)$ with intensity $\lambda dt$, where $\lambda\in(0,\infty)$. Let $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of independent random variables, independent of $M$ and distributed uniformly on $[0,1]$. Given a measurable function $g$ on $[0,1]$, define $$X_t=X_t^g=\sum_{n=1}^{N_t}g(Y_n)$$ where $N_t=M(0,t]$.

I have shown, using partitioning of the expectation and Fubini, that in the case $g\geq0$ we have $$\mathbb{E}(X_t)=\lambda t\int_0^1g(y)dy.$$ I am now tasked to find a necessary and sufficient condition on $g$ for $(X_t)_{t\geq0}$ to be a martingale.

My thinking was that, according to the OST, a necessary and sufficient condition is $\mathbb{E}(X_T)=\mathbb{E}(X_0)=0$ for all bounded stopping times $T$. Suppose that $g\geq0$. Then from the formula above, we see that for any $t>0$, we require that $g\equiv0$ on $[0,1]$ otherwise $\mathbb{E}(X_t)>0$. So I feel that it will be necessary for $g$ to be non-positive. I do not know how to proceed from here though, so would greatly appreciate advice.

Comment: Martingale with respect to what filtration more exactly? Only the natural filtration of the Poisson process or compounding with the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(Y_n: n\in \mathbb{N})$ as well?

Comment: In the latter case, a necessary and sufficient condition, if I am not missing anything is $\mathbb{E}\left[g(Y)\right]=0$.

Comment: My answer was not correct and I deleted it. Thank you.

Comment: For my comment regarding Fubini - I actually am not sure if it is necessary as the expectation is a linear operator and so for a finite sum we should be able to interchange the sum and expectation anyway. However I am now confused as the question (question 6 on https://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/postgrad/part-iii/files/pastpapers/2019/paper_201.pdf) specifies the case that $g\geq0$ for part b, but now I am unsure why that is necessary.

Comment: My argument was wrong at the following identity: $\mathbb{E}\left[\sum\limits_{n=1}^{M\left.\left[s,t\right.\right)}g(Y_n)\left|\widetilde{\mathcal{F}}_s\right.\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\sum\limits_{n=1}^{M\left.\left[s,t\right.\right)}g(Y_n)\right]$, which is not granted to hold in general since $g(Y_n)$ is not independent of $\widetilde{\mathcal{F}}_t=\sigma(\mathcal{F}_t,\Sigma)$, with $\Sigma=\sigma(Y_n\,:\,n\in\mathbb{N})$ and $\mathcal{F}_t$ the natural filtration of the Poisson process. I will try to correct it and post if I find an alternative.

Comment: I think that the filtration defined by $\mathcal{F}_t=\sigma(X_s:s\leq t)$ is sufficient for the purposes of this question? And this is seemingly the most natural filtration to use, given that the question does not specify. Then we have $\mathbb{E}(X_t|\mathcal{F}_s)=X_s+\mathbb{E}(\sum_{n=N_s+1}^{N_t}g(Y_n)|\mathcal{F}_s)$ with the term on the right being just the normal expectation as these $g(Y_n)$, and $N_t$, will be independent of $\mathcal{F}_s$.

Comment: Indeed, I think this corrects the solution I posted. Let me check.

Comment: Great thanks, in that case I'm just wondering why they added that $g\geq0$ in the conditions for part b) of the question, as it seems unnecessary if Fubini isn't being used

Comment: If $X$ is a nonnegative random variable, i.e., $X\geq0$, then, $E(X)=0$ implies $X=0$ almost surely. Therefore, if $g\geq 0$ then, $E(g(Y))=0$ implies that $g(Y)=0$ almost surely and this holds iff $g=0$ given that $Y$ is uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{F}_t$ be the natural filtration of the process $\left(X_t\right)_{t\geq 0}$.

**Claim.** $\left(X_t\right)_{t\geq 0}$ is a martingale w.r.t. $\mathcal{F}_t$ if and only if $\mathbb{E}\left[g(Y)\right]=0$.

*Proof.*  For any $s<t$, we have
$\mathbb{E}\left[X_t\left|\mathcal{F}_s\right.\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N_t}g(Y_n)\left|\mathcal{F}_s\right.\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N_s}g(Y_n)\left|\mathcal{F}_s\right.\right]+\mathbb{E}\left[\sum\limits_{n>N_s}^{N_s+M\left.\left[s,t\right.\right)}g(Y_n)\left|\mathcal{F}_s\right.\right]=X_s+\mathbb{E}\left[\sum\limits_{n>N_s}^{N_s+M\left.\left[s,t\right.\right)}g(Y_n)\right]$,

and

$\mathbb{E}\left[\sum\limits_{n>N_s}^{N_s+M\left.\left[s,t\right.\right)}g(Y_n)\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N_{t-s}}g(Y_n)\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N_{t-s}}g(Y_{n+N_{t-s}})\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N_{t-s}}g(Y_{n+N_{t-s}})\left|\mathcal{F}_{t-s}\right.\right]\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N_{t-s}}\mathbb{E}\left[g(Y_{n+N_{t-s}})\left|\mathcal{F}_{t-s}\right.\right]\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N_{t-s}}\mathbb{E}\left[g(Y)\right]\right]=\lambda(t-s)\mathbb{E}\left[g(Y)\right]$,

which is zero if and only if $\mathbb{E}\left[g(Y)\right]=0$.

If $g\geq 0$ then, $\mathbb{E}\left[g(Y)\right]=0\Rightarrow g=0$ almost everywhere in $\left[0,1\right]$.