# When is compound Poisson process a martingale?

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, poisson-process

here's my proof of a claim that the Compound Poisson Process (CPP for short) is a martingale $\iff$ the expected value of the iid random variables we are summing is $0$.

A stochastic process $X_t$ adapted to the filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq0}$ is a martingale if the following condition holds:
$$
E\left[X_t\mid\mathcal{F}_s\right] = X_s
$$
for every $0\leq s < t$.

We want to show that, in general, a Compound Poisson Process (CPP) is not a martingale.

Claim:

Let $(S_t)_{t\geq0}$ be a CPP with intensity $\lambda>0$, and let $X_i$ be independent and identically distributed random variables with $E\left[X_i\right] = \mu$ for each $i$. Then, $S_t$ is a martingale if and only if $\mu = 0$.

Proof:

Consider $0\leq s\leq t$. We have
\begin{align*}
    E\left[S_t\mid\mathcal{F}_s\right] 
            &= E\left[S_t - S_s + S_s\mid \mathcal{F}_s\right] \\
            &= E\left[S_t - S_s\right] + E\left[S_s\mid \mathcal{F}_s\right] \\
            & \text{recall that} \ E\left[S_t\right] = \mu\lambda t \\
            &= \mu\lambda(t-s) + S_s
\end{align*}
The equality $\mu\lambda(t-s) + S_s = S_s$ holds $\iff$ $\mu\lambda(t-s) = 0 \iff \mu = 0$.

I'm wondering if there is any fault in my proof, or is it fine?

Comment: yeah it looks fine

Comment: A slightly more general version: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4446288/necessary-and-sufficient-condition-for-random-sum-of-independent-rvs-to-be-a-mar/4446534#4446534